# Suspected open neutral in light switch box - finding the source

Tags: electrical

I went to install a smart switch that requires a neutral wire. Everything was hooked up correctly but the switch wasn't working - the old regular switch didn't use the neutral.
I started testing the different voltages with my multimeter and got the following reads:

Hot - ground: ~120V

Hot - neutral: 10V

Ground - neutral: 1.6V

Am I right to think this is an open neutral issue? All of the outlets on this circuit appear to be working normally. Any suggestions on diagnosing the source of the issue?

Comment: Old switches often used a switch loop where the white was(suppose to be) lways hot and the black was the switch hot.  This would be the case if just a single cable with black/white wires went to the switch box.  You would have neutral with two cables, one with power from the panel.  Two blacks on the switch, and the two whites(neutrals) connected together.

Comment: Sounds like possibly a [switch loop](https://www.finehomebuilding.com/project-guides/wiring/wiring-a-switch-loop). Can you [edit] your question to add a photo of the wiring at the switch and at the light box? Turn off the breaker to the circuit and pull them out before photographing but don't disconnect them.

Comment: Can you add a picture of the switch box clearly showing cables and wires with the old switch connected exactly as it was?    Is there a red wire in the box?  Was there a white wire in the box not connected to anything when the old switch was installed?